# Hide some array elements in Elasticsearch query result

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I index objects in Elasticsearch 2.4 where one of the fields is an array of other objects, for example, something like this:

```
{
 A : 1,
 B : [{BB : 1},{BB : 2},{BB : 4},{BB : 5}]
}
```

Is it possible to query Elasticsearch and apply a filter to hide some of the arrays's **`B`** values, for example, to hide values where `BB` is less than 3 such that a result would be

```
{
 A : 1,
 B : [{BB : 4},{BB : 5}]
}
```

P.S.
I'm using Java API

Comment: You should explain the "hide" concept further. It sounds like a custom need. If it is, it means you will problably need a custom solution. I don't think ELS provides this kind of feature.

Comment: By hiding I mean something like postfiltering source fields. Ideally what I'd like to have is something like passing a lambda to ES to transform every hit to something that I need.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a flexible built in way of doing it so I decided to filter manually. Here's my implementation:

```
SearchResponse resp = request.execute().actionGet();
for (SearchHit hit : resp.getHits().getHits()) {
    Map<String, Object> source = hit.getSource();

    transformHitSource(source); // a method where you work with a map and can modify it as you want


    XContentBuilder xContentBuilder = jsonBuilder().startObject();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : source.entrySet()) {
        xContentBuilder.field(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    BytesReference bytes = xContentBuilder.endObject().bytes();
    ((InternalSearchHit) hit).sourceRef(bytes);
}
```